# Functions and returning multiple elements python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program about poker game and for the comparison part I called (returned) multiples values for each set up.

In this case, I returned an array, one of them was a boolien and one of them was an integer. But when I tried to use them in another function I get an error **('bool' object is not subscriptable)** and I dont know why. My whole code is nearly 150 line and for running it you ll need extra file so I ll share some parts of it.

these are the set up parts for each combination

```
def straight(n):
    F = converter(n)
    if consecutive(F) == True:
        return [True, F[0]]
    return False


def full_house(n):
    F = converter(n)
    if len(set(F)) == 2:
        for i in F:
            if F.count(i) == 3:
                return [True, i]
    return False
```

this is the part where I will rank them

```
def ranking(n, k):
    if n == "AKQJT" and flush(k) == True:
        return 9
    elif  straight(n)[0]== True and flush(k) == True:
        return [8,straight(n)[1]]

    elif four_kind(n)[0]== True:
        return [7,four_kind(n)[1]]

    elif (full_house(n))[0]== True:
        return [6,full_house(n)[1]]

    elif flush(k) == True:
        return 5

    elif (straight(n))[0]== True:
        return [4,straight(n)[1]]
```

for example when I try

```
print(ranking("44447","DDDDD"))
```

I get an error

```
 elif  straight(n)[0]== True and flush(k) == True: line ...
 TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

**But** interstingly when I try the straight flush (the second elif part tests it). For example,

```
print(ranking("23456","DDDDD")
```

I get an answer like

```
[8,6]
```

which its the true answer but then again I get the same error.

Comment: Because you're returning two different types, you can't assume you'll always get an array. Why not just return an array with a None in the False case?

Comment: it looks like `straight(n)` returns a boolean value and you are trying to index it with `[0]`. Indeed `straight ` may return `False`.

Comment: pass a pointer reference for them in the parameters of the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default case, you do not return an array:

```
    return False
```

Change it to something like

```
    return [False, None]
```

or whatever makes sense for your situation.

Comment: I thought that if its false then it would just pass that line and jump to another elif I never thought this actually. It seems like problem is solved

Comment: Realistically, the whole function should just be changed to `return i` and `return None` instead of a pair at all, but that’s outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: That makes much more sense..I ll try that

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout what you are returning through **straight(n)**. I believe in this case you are trying to return **False**. So, Boolean is not subscript-able.

If you get get straight(n) as False. You cannot write if-elif conditions to verify their cases. You need to design nested loops for cases straight(n) is False and straight(n) is not equal to False.